# Android VideoView stutters at beginning after running for approx 24 hours

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, kiosk

I have an app that is designed to play a series of videos in a loop 24x7 (This will be installed in kiosk mode). Everything seems to be working, but after about 24 hours running the videos begin to stutter right at the beginning. Videos play right from the filesystem so network latency is not the issue.

My log messages don't show anything obvious. When each video starts, I get one of these: `W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)`. Then one of these approximately each second while the video plays: `W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)`. I can't find any information on this second status code.

I don't suspect a memory leak, as my usage hovers around 2.5MB continuously. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Edit: I did actually find these in the global logcat. They occur during the stutter. Anybody know what this means and/or have insight into a solution?

```
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
D/ISystemWriteService(  115): readSysfs could not contact remote
D/ISystemWriteService(  115): readSysfs could not contact remote
D/ISystemWriteService(  115): readSysfs could not contact remote
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
I/amplayer( 6310): **[update_state]pid:26 status=PLAYING(last:PLAYING) err=0x0 curtime=4 (ms:4473) fulltime=30 lsttime=4
I/amplayer( 6310): **[update_state]abuflevel=0.18177669 vbublevel=0.34421411 abufrp=9871880 vbufrp=7b46200 read_end=1
V/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): update_process pid=26, current=4,status=[PLAYING]
V/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): Playing percent =13,mPlayTime:4473,mStreamTime:4473
V/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): Playing percent on percent=99,bufed pos=7223869,Duration=7249275
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [notify::498]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [Notify::505]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): cookie=0xb7307d40,msg=3,ext1=63,ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerService( 6310): [27] notify (0xb723d660, 3, 99, 0)
D/ISystemWriteService(  115): readSysfs could not contact remote
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [notify::498]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [Notify::505]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): cookie=0xb7307d40,msg=c8,ext1=9001,ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerService( 6310): [27] notify (0xb723d660, 200, 36865, 0)
I/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): Got amplayer download speed : 0 kbps
D/ISystemWriteService(  115): readSysfs could not contact remote
D/ISystemWriteService(  115): readSysfs could not contact remote
W/MediaPlayer( 7190): info/warning (36865, 0)
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
I/amplayer( 6310): **[update_state]pid:26 status=PLAYING(last:PLAYING) err=0x0 curtime=5 (ms:5007) fulltime=30 lsttime=4
I/amplayer( 6310): **[update_state]abuflevel=0.17787044 vbublevel=0.34024277 abufrp=9873080 vbufrp=7b55600 read_end=1
V/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): update_process pid=26, current=5,status=[PLAYING]
V/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): Playing percent =14,mPlayTime:5007,mStreamTime:5007
V/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): Playing percent on percent=99,bufed pos=7223869,Duration=7249275
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [notify::498]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [Notify::505]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): cookie=0xb7307d40,msg=3,ext1=63,ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerService( 6310): [27] notify (0xb723d660, 3, 99, 0)
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [notify::498]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): [Notify::505]
V/AmSuperPlayer( 6310): cookie=0xb7307d40,msg=c8,ext1=9001,ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerService( 6310): [27] notify (0xb723d660, 200, 36865, 0)
I/AmlogicPlayer( 6310): Got amplayer download speed : 0 kbps
W/MediaPlayer( 7190): info/warning (36865, 0)
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
W/AudioFlinger( 6310): OutputTrack::write() 0xb36e8008 thread 0xb6ffebc8 no more overflow buffers
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer, but a suggestion.
I have had similar issues with amlogic based devices.

The app I was making which handled a lot of images and video live streams, was basically running fine until device has been on for 24 hours+, like you mentioned. The only thing that has fixed my issue, was to switch to ART (Android Runtime) instead of Dalvik.